# How to add elements from nested collections to List<string>?

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON which is written as:

```
{"Groups":[{
"UniqueId": "Group-1",
"Title": "",
"Subtitle": "",
"ImagePath": "",
"Description" : "",
"Items":
[
  {
    "UniqueId": "",
    "Title": "",
    "Subtitle": "",
    "ImagePath": "",
    "Description" : "",
    "Content" : ""
  }]}]}
```

I am able to add `Title` from `Groups` using the following code:

```
List<string> titles = new List<string>();

if (this._groups.Count != 0)
{
    titles.AddRange(_sampleDataSource.Groups.Select(x => x.Title));
}
```

But I want to add `Title` from items also and I am unable to do so. I have tried the following code:

```
List<string> titles = new List<string>();

if (this._groups.Count != 0)
{
    titles.AddRange(_sampleDataSource.Groups.Select(x => x.Items.Select(y => y.Title)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to flatten list:

```
titles.AddRange(_sampleDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Items.Select(y => y.Title)));
```

What you had, was creating an enumerable with enumerables inside (figuratively speaking: a list of lists), so the resulting type was `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, which was not what `AddRange` was expecting (`IEnumerable<string>`).

`SelectMany` takes a "list of lists" and creates one "list" containing elements from all these lists together (more strictly they are instances of `IEnumerable`, not `List<T>`, it just sounds easier).